# Submitting paper to arXiv as an undergrad

Tags: research-process, research-undergraduate, arxiv

I wrote a rather extensive research project for one of my courses, and would like to submit it to arXiv. But, I am not entirely sure about the copyright/other issues behind it. Is it acceptable for a student to submit their term papers online, and in doing so can I, as an undergrad, claim affiliation to my university?

Comment: I'd sit down and have a chit-chat with the professor who supervised the report. They'll have a good feel if it's suitable for submission. arXiv might not even be the best place for it -- could be worth submitting to a conference/journal.

Comment: Arxiv's primary purpose isn't to publish work, it's to distribute preprints and reprints of work that has been published in a journal. Why would there be a copyright issue? In the US, if you wrote it, you own the copyright.

Comment: @Matthew: Submitting to the arxiv is not incompatible with submitting the paper to a conference or journal.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark true-- I was just suggesting that arXiv might not be the only destination.

Comment: @BenCrowell I'm an arXiv moderator, and I've _never_ heard arXiv's purpose described that way. ArXiv's purpose is to make research papers freely and easily available, period.

Comment: @BenCrowell: I agree with JeffE. There are fields (string theory, for instance) which uses arXiv _in place of_ traditional journal publication.

Comment: Maybe we can agree that, in some areas, the principal use of the arXiv is to distribute preprints which will eventually be published in journals.

Comment: In any case, the OP should be aware that the attitudes of journals toward previous dissemination, via the arXiv or otherwise, vary a lot by field.  As Matthew G. said, you should discuss this with the professor who supervised the project.

Comment: @JeffE: You're right, of course. But... somehow I feel that this situation is qualitatively different from the situation of a string theorist posting results on arxiv and not feeling that publication in a refereed journal is relevant. I think the difference is that in the former situation, unlike the latter, it's virtually guaranteed that nobody will read the paper.

Answer (score 1):

I will leave the question of whether or not you *should* submit the paper to arXiv versus another venue for discussion elsewhere. However, I do agree with the comment that you should talk with the professor who gave you the assignment about your plans, as he or she may have constructive criticism for you.

In general, if your work represents an original contribution, and you feel comfortable with sharing it with the public, then yes, you can go ahead and submit it to arXiv. You should note, however, that in a number of fields, papers cannot be submitted until you have been *endorsed*—that is, recognized as a valid submitter by someone who has already themselves submitted a number of papers in that area. If the professor of the course is someone who can endorse you, then that should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

It is acceptable for an undergraduate student to publish.
However, please consult it with someone in the field (to make it a decent publication - both in terms of its content and form).

Copyright/authorship - it should be not an issue (unless it contains notes from the course or something). In case of doubt - ask your lecturer/TA.

Affiliation is a bit more tricky (especially if your program is not directly linked to a research department, or - is linked to many). Two typical choices are: one related to your program or one directly related to this course.

In many cases, the university will be happy to have one more publication with their affiliation (or won't care). In some, there are some strict rules when you can add their affiliation (e.g. you need approval of a prof.).